# as3 scaleX by percent of mc size

Tags: actionscript-3, percentage

How do I scale the X of an mc by a percentage?

For example I have the var percent. It starts at zero and goes to 100. But `mx.scaleX = 33;` will not work it needs to be .33 or .3 but again my numbers I am working with is 0 though 100 and I need the percentage of that to be written in a ways that the scaleX can handle it.

```
// other code to get correct percent; // result is 0 through 100
yellowProgress.scaleX = percent;
```

Comment: yellowProgress.scaleX = percent / 100;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `percent` is 100, `scaleX` should be 1 - so:

1 (as `percent`) is 1% of 100 (maximum `percent`), so you need 1% of 1 (maximum `scaleX`) which is 0.01. To get 1% of something, just divide it by 100.

So `yellowProgress.scaleX = percent / 100;` will do the trick.